# Code Behind executes but not the intended JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site for the company I work in so they can have an overview of the activities they got going for saving and earning money for the company.

It's made with ASP.NET but I have a small issue. When the user successfully added an activity they are redirected to a site that shows the pending activities (as they need to be approved before they are put in production). When they arrive at the new page I want to use a bootstrap modal I placed on the page from to tell them what the ID is of their new activity but it doesn't work (however the below works on other pages where I use it, though I have not used it after a redirect anywhere else).

It redirects to the correct page but the Alert doesn't appear. Below is the code that I use when the `LoadComplete` event fires:

```
void Pending_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
    {
        String query = Request.QueryString.Get(0);
        String jsExec = Util.ModalAlert(query, "#info_modal", ".modal-body");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "ModalAlertShow", jsExec, false);
    }
}
```

The `Util.ModalAlert()` method:

```
public static String ModalAlert(String message, String modalId, String modalBodyId)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    if (modalBodyId.StartsWith("."))
    {
        sb.AppendLine("$('"+ modalId + " " + modalBodyId + "').html('" + message + "');");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.AppendLine("$('" + modalId + modalBodyId + "').html('" + message + "');");
    }

    sb.AppendLine("$('" + modalId + "').modal('show');");
    sb.AppendLine("</script>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I checked in the debugger that the code actually runs and it does, but alas the Modal does not appear on the page I redirect to. The Modal Body doesn't even have the text that is supposed to be in it. it's just empty. I have a suspicion that the page reloads when I fire that script or LoadComplete doesn't work like I think it does.

Any idea why?

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) what is "pending"? how do you wire this event handler into the page (when is it called)? 2) can you show the relevant markup? 3) are you sure necessary jquery ui script is linked to the page?

Comment: Change the last parameter from false to true this will automatically add the script tag if I am not mistaken. 
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "ModalAlertShow", jsExec, true);` also like @Andrei had mentioned, show the aspx markup in how you are calling this